# How to pass multiple input text value to method in controller

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, model-view-controller

I having 3 textbox and I want to send value enter over there to controller method

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="id" name="id">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="id1" name="id1">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="id2" name="id2">

@Html.ActionLink("Send", "MethodNameInController", "ColtrollerName", new { id= $('#id').val(), 
id1= $('#id1').val(), id2= $('#id2').val()})
```

and in controller
public ActionResult MethodNameInController(int id, string id1, string id2)
{
//some text here
}

but it's sending null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution using ajax just want to know is there any direct solution

```
$(function () {
    $('#receipt').unbind('click');
    $('#receipt').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Controller/Method",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                fromDate: $("#fromDate").val(),
                toDate: $("#toDate").val(),
                id: $("#id").val()
                
            }),
            async: false
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay on the same view or redirect to another url after, instead of using `@Html.ActionLink()` try passing the values to the controller using an ajax call.

```js
function submitAjax(){

        //purely for readability
        var id = $('#id').val();
        var id1 = $('#id1').val();
        var id2 = $('#id2').val();

        //ajax call
        $.ajax({
        url: "/ControllerName/MethodNameInController",
        data: { id: id, id1: id1, id2: id2 },
        success: function (result) {
            //handle something here
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="id" name="id">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="id1" name="id1">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="id2" name="id2">

<button type="button" onclick="submitAjax()">submit</button>
```

If the method does some processing and then returns you to a different view, you could do a form submit.

```js
function submitForm(){
      var $form = $("#idForm");
      //optional validation
      
      $form.submit();
};
```

```html
<form id="idForm" class="form-horizontal" asp-controller="ControllerName" asp-action="MethodNameInController" >
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="id" name="id">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="id1" name="id1">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="id2" name="id2">

  <!-- type="button" prevents the from from submitting so you can do validation checks in the js -->
  <button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">submit</button>
</form>
```